# Are there any games to kickstart learning emacs like VIM Adventures?

Tags: learning

I am a newbie in emacs and have heard a lot about how powerful emacs is. But the leaning curve seems to be quite steep. If there was a fun way to learn emacs (something like the game [VIM adventures](http://vim-adventures.com/)) that could help me quickly to familiarize the key binding and modes, I could dig deeper into more advanced features of emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't nearly as gamified as Vim Adventures, but [keywiz](http://users-phys.au.dk/harder/keywiz.el) has points, time limits, and high scores; maybe that's enough to qualify it as a game.

Comment: Link is broken.